# Laravel Input::hasFile('image') returns false even if a File is uploaded

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-4.2

I have a Form field for an Image upload, which I open with 'files' => true, like so:

```
{{ Form::label('image', 'Image') }}
{{ Form::file('image') }}
```

And in my Controller I want to check if a File was uploaded and do something with it:

```
if (Input::hasFile('image')){
        $in_path = 'img/';
        $in_extension = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = Input::get('name').".".$in_extension;
        Input::file('image')->move($in_path, $filename);
        $user->image = $filename;
    }
```

But `Input::hasFile` always returns false and I don't know why.

```
Input::file('image');
```

results in:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object
(
[test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 
[originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => test.JPG
[mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => application/octet-stream
[size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0
[error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 1
[pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => 
[fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => 
)
```

**I have tested around with another picture for another User and this works fine. I don't get why this is working for some Users and for some others not.**

Is there maybe some kind of Pictures that are not accepted?

What other sources could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: The file exists? Is it uploaded? Can you post what's inside `Input::file()`. Use `dd()` for var_dumping.

Comment: I solved what was wrong. The code is fine, but the problem was some pictures were simply to big.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I solved what was wrong.
The code is fine, but the problem was some pictures were simply to big.


**EDIT:**

As Don't Panic pointed out, editing `upload_max_filesize` can solve the problem.

Comment: why is a big picture returning hasfile() -> false?

Comment: @Jorre I can't answer that ... But everything worked on smaller pictures.

Comment: This is _not_ better as a comment just because it's short. It is the answer, and it's perfectly valid. I had the same problem and arrived at the same solution. Increasing `upload_max_filesize` just a bit took care of it.

Comment: One thing important to note is I also had to change post_max_size to be greater than upload_max_filesize.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem, I checked my code and noticed that I had not the enctype="multipart/form-data" header in the form, hope that this big neglect help anyone

Answer (score 7):

How do you open your form? If you want your form to accept files you need so open it like this:

```
echo Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar', 'files' => true))
```

[Opening a form in the Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/html#opening-a-form)

Answer (score 1):

For people using later versions of laravel

Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as a form attribute, also ensure that the `method` is `POST`

`<form action="/foo" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Regards