# getRealPath() returns false (Laravel 5.2 & Image Intervention)

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5, enctype

When uploading images, `getRealPath()` always returns `false`:

```
$image_file = $request->file('image_file');
$image_file->getRealPath(); // ---> FALSE
```

Here is the result of `dd($image_file);`:

[image]

Also, when I try to use it with Image Intervention:

```
        $image_file = $request->file('image_file');

        Image::make($image_file->getRealPath())->.....
```

I am getting the following error:

> NotReadableException in AbstractDecoder.php line 323: Image source not
>   readable

Obviously because `getRealPath()` returns `false`... Someone has already asked about this problem: [getRealPath returning false (Image Intervention and Laravel 5.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33421090/getrealpath-returning-false-image-intervention-and-laravel-5-1) ... but there is no solution.

Do you know why is this happening, how can I fix this?

Comment: is your picture size is big ? see this answer if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929197/laravel-inputhasfileimage-returns-false-even-if-a-file-is-uploaded?rq=1

Comment: @Vikash No, the image size is 16kb, so no, that is not a problem.

Comment: @PeraMika Have you tried (like the guy on the post you linked) to avoid using `getRealPath()` method and use `public_path()` method instead? That should resolve your problem.

Comment: @Mihailo Yes, like this: `$request->file('image_file')->public_path()` and I am getting **Method public_path does not exist.**.

Comment: You can not **"chain"**. Try `public_path($request->file('image_file')->getClientOriginalName())` instead.

Comment: you can check this issue https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/26

Comment: @Mihailo No it doesn't work... The `public_path` function returns the fully qualified path to the public directory, and I need a getRealPath() which gets absolute path to TEMP file that was just uploaded (located in C:\Windows\**Temp**... not in the project's public directory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in **php.ini** - incorrect upload dir.

Comment: can you please share the error that was found in php.ini file of yours. i am facing same problem i don't see any problem with my ini file also my temp upload path is C:\Windows\Temp but still not getting path by ->getRealpath() function its returning false

Comment: just set a custom upload_tmp_dir other than the system default

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with the `getRealPath()`. It returns false when I `dd()`.
Try using `$request->getPathname()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on L8. Was getting the same error when trying to upload images via Intervention. Was able to confirm the defaults were correct in the php.ini, and located the Temp folder on the system. I was able to correct this on my new server by adding write permissions to the User on the default C:Windows/Temp folder.