# Laravel can't save photo

Tags: php, laravel

I have function code below but it won't save photo not in database nor in file path.

## Code

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'name' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required|numeric',
            'type_id' => 'required|numeric',
            'photo' => 'required',
        ));
        $item = new Menu;
        $item->name = $request->input('name');
        $item->price = $request->input('price');
        $item->type_id = $request->input('type_id');
        if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
          $photo = $request->file('photo');
          $filename = 'MenuItem' . '-' . time() . '.' . $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
          $location = public_path('images/'. $filename);
          Image::make($photo)->resize(500, 500)->save($location);
          $item->photo = $filename;
        }
        $item->save();
        Session::flash('success', 'Menu Item Saved Successfully.');
        return redirect()->back();
}
```

## `dd($request->all());` of code above

```
array:5 [▼
  "_token" => "awAvc7F8lOv9vKkfwyiTFj7jnQGszv8xjLQxcwRH"
  "name" => "test"
  "price" => "100"
  "photo" => "air putih.jpg"
  "type_id" => "1"
]
```

Any idea?

## Update

Based on the `Nabil Farhan` answer below I was forgot about `enctype="multipart/form-data"` but now I'm getting

```
Intervention \ Image \ Exception \ NotReadableException
Unable to find file ().
```

**Still not able to save my photo.**

## Update 2

I dd my requests again, now after adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` it becomes strange:

```
array:5 [▼
  "_token" => "awAvc7F8lOv9vKkfwyiTFj7jnQGszv8xjLQxcwRH"
  "name" => "kerupuk"
  "price" => "2000"
  "type_id" => "3"
  "photo" => UploadedFile {#805 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "kerupuk.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "C:\Windows\Temp"
    filename: "phpB195.tmp"
    basename: "phpB195.tmp"
    pathname: "C:\Windows\Temp\phpB195.tmp"
    extension: "tmp"
    realPath: false
    aTime: 2019-02-12 04:57:39
    mTime: 2019-02-12 04:57:39
    cTime: 2019-02-12 04:57:39
    inode: 0
    size: 43933
    perms: 0100666
    owner: 0
    group: 0
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
    linkTarget: "C:\Windows\Temp\phpB195.tmp"
  }
]
```

Why my photo field becomes like that?!

anyway here is my form in blade:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'menus.store', 'files' => true)) }}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h5>Name</h5>
      {{ Form::text('name', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h5>Price</h5>
      {{ Form::number('price', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h5>Photo</h5>
      {{ Form::file('photo', array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'photo')) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h5>Type</h5>
        <select name="type_id" id="type_id" class="form-control">
            <option value="">-- Select --</option>
            @foreach($types as $type)
            <option value="{{$type->id}}">{{$type->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 mt-2">
      {{ Form::submit('Save', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
    </div>
  </div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: Can you update your form code here.

Comment: @Md.SukelAli updated

Comment: @mafortis your realpath is false  some thing error in config

Comment: refer this two links 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41900565/getrealpath-returns-false-laravel-5-2-image-intervention


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531408/setting-php-tmp-dir-php-upload-not-working

Answer (score 1):

The `"photo" => "air putih.jpg"` should not be a string. It should have some more information regarding file.

I think the problem is in your blade file. Please check if you have used `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in your form tag.

**EDIT**

Change this

```
Image::make($photo)->resize(500, 500)->save($location);
```

To this

```
Image::make($photo->getRealPath())->resize(500, 500)->save($location);
```

Comment: awesome i was totally forgot about that :) . now i'm gertting `Unable to find file ().`

Comment: please try now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line

```
Image::make($photo)->resize(500, 500)->save($location);


Image::make($photo->getRealPath())->resize('200','200')->save($location);
```

Your realpath is false check config

Comment: as I commented in nabil answer that returns `Image source not readable`

Comment: Your laravel version??

Comment: can you dump the  $location

Comment: `"C:\laragon\www\hrdapp\public\images/MenuItem-1549948461.jpg"`

Comment: what is your drive type  'imagick' or 'gd'  also check permission to folder public

Comment: imagick gives error that requires some extensions so i'm using default gd

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

**Your view file like this**:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'menus.store', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' => 'form', 'method' => 'post','files'=>true]) !!}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h5>Name</h5>
      {{ Form::text('name', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h5>Price</h5>
      {{ Form::number('price', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h5>Photo</h5>
      {{ Form::file('photo', array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'photo')) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h5>Type</h5>
        <select name="type_id" id="type_id" class="form-control">
            <option value="">-- Select --</option>
            @foreach($types as $type)
            <option value="{{$type->id}}">{{$type->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 mt-2">
      {{ Form::submit('Save', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
    </div>
  </div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**Your controller function like this**:

```
use Input;

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'name' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required|numeric',
            'type_id' => 'required|numeric',
            'photo' => 'required',
        ));
        $item = new Menu;
        $item->name = $request->input('name');
        $item->price = $request->input('price');
        $item->type_id = $request->input('type_id');
        if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
          $photo = Input::file('photo');
          $filename = 'MenuItem' . '-' . time() . '.' . $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
          $location = public_path('images/'. $filename);
          $img = Image::make($photo->getRealPath());
          $img->resize(500, 500, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
          })->save($location);
          $item->photo = $filename;
        }
        $item->save();
        Session::flash('success', 'Menu Item Saved Successfully.');
        return redirect()->back();
}
```